# Open every file in a folder one by one

Tags: php, cron

I created a flat file database containing lots of small php files.

Each file contains something like:

```
<?php
$amount = 350;
$status = 1;
$steamid = 76561198046273125;
?>
```

They are named like the $steamid they contain. In this case 76561198046273125.php.

I would like to use a cron job to execute a php file which decreases the $amount variable by 10 every 10 minutes. I managed to do this by opening a file via:

```
$userinfo = fopen("users/76561198046273125.php") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Then

```
$amount = $amount - 10;
```

and then "fwrite" it down again.

Since with every new user a new file is created, I don't have a list of all the filenames.

How can I make a script cycle through the whole "users" folder and make every file run through this process without giving a list of filenames?

---

EDIT:
So something like this could work?

```
<?php
foreach (glob('users/*.php') as $userfile) {
   $userinfo = fopen("$userfile") or die("Unable to open file!");

   //...do some actions here...

}
?>
```

Comment: Read the list of filenames from the folder using [glob()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) or [scandir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Comment: https://secure.php.net/glob

Comment: I added something to my original post. Is this right?

Comment: Made it work this way! Thanks for the help! Love!

Comment: `fopen("$userfile")`.... why are you wrapping `$userfile` in quotes?

Comment: I dont know. Probably because I don't know better. How do I know when to wrap something in quotes and when not? Thanks for the hint. I am already googling. :)

Comment: If it's a literal string value, then it needs to be quoted, e.g. `echo "Hello World";` ; if you're "interpolating" a variable as part of a larger string, then you may need to quote it (there are other options), e.g. `echo "The file is named $userfile"`; but otherwise you don't need to quote a variable

Comment: Okay, learned something new. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to operate on one of those variables inside an external file and update its value. Fopen will open your file as a simple text file not as a php file. For that you have to use [file_get_contents()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) with [eval()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). You get the internal variables, decrease the amount, prepare all the text again and overwrite the original file.

Try something along these lines:

```
foreach (glob("/your/path/to/users/folder/*.php") as $filename) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    eval($contents);
    $amount = $amount - 10;

    $new_string = "
        <?php\n
            \$amount = $amount;\n
            \$status = $status;\n
            \$steamid = $steamid;\n
        ?>"
    ;
    file_put_contents($filename, $new_string);
}
```

Ps. beware of the dangers of eval();

Comment: The operation on the file itself already works. The file should be opened as a textfile, changed, saved and is included in another php file if needed. My problem is (or was - we will see), to cycle through a whole folder of items without knowhing their names.

Comment: I have changed the path in the glob function, you will have to edit that

Comment: Hey, this was far easier than expected. I am new to php and didn't know the glob command. Thanks a lot!